# What is the second `r2` return value in Go's Syscall() for?

Tags: go, system-calls

Here is [Go's undocumented Syscall function](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Syscall):

```
func Syscall(trap, a1, a2, a3 uintptr) (r1, r2 uintptr, err Errno)
```

And here is [the C definition](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html):

```
long syscall(long number, ...);
```

Pretty different. So it's fairly obvious that `trap` is `number`, and `a1`, `a2`, and `a3` allow for three arguments. I also worked out that `r1` is the return value, and `err` is `errno`. But what is `r2`? The syscall man page doesn't mention multiple return values.

It does give the actual calling conventions (still only one retval):

```
       arch/ABI    instruction           syscall #  retval  error    Notes
       ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
       alpha       callsys               v0         a0      a3       [1]
       arc         trap0                 r8         r0      -
       arm/OABI    swi NR                -          a1      -        [2]
       arm/EABI    swi 0x0               r7         r0      -
       arm64       svc #0                x8         x0      -
       blackfin    excpt 0x0             P0         R0      -
       i386        int $0x80             eax        eax     -
       ia64        break 0x100000        r15        r8      r10      [1]
       m68k        trap #0               d0         d0      -
       microblaze  brki r14,8            r12        r3      -
       mips        syscall               v0         v0      a3       [1]
       nios2       trap                  r2         r2      r7
       parisc      ble 0x100(%sr2, %r0)  r20        r28     -
       powerpc     sc                    r0         r3      r0       [1]
       s390        svc 0                 r1         r2      -        [3]
       s390x       svc 0                 r1         r2      -        [3]
       superh      trap #0x17            r3         r0      -        [4]
       sparc/32    t 0x10                g1         o0      psr/csr  [1]
       sparc/64    t 0x6d                g1         o0      psr/csr  [1]
       tile        swint1                R10        R00     R01      [1]
       x86_64      syscall               rax        rax     -        [5]
       x32         syscall               rax        rax     -        [5]
       xtensa      syscall               a2         a2      -
```

But on x86 this is [the implementation](https://golang.org/src/syscall/asm_linux_386.s)

```
    #define INVOKE_SYSCALL  INT $0x80

    TEXT    ·Syscall(SB),NOSPLIT,$0-28
        CALL    runtime·entersyscall(SB)
        MOVL    trap+0(FP), AX  // syscall entry
        MOVL    a1+4(FP), BX
        MOVL    a2+8(FP), CX
        MOVL    a3+12(FP), DX
        MOVL    $0, SI
        MOVL    $0,  DI
        INVOKE_SYSCALL
        CMPL    AX, $0xfffff001
        JLS ok
        MOVL    $-1, r1+16(FP)
        MOVL    $0, r2+20(FP)
        NEGL    AX
        MOVL    AX, err+24(FP)
        CALL    runtime·exitsyscall(SB)
        RET
    ok:
        MOVL    AX, r1+16(FP)
        MOVL    DX, r2+20(FP)
        MOVL    $0, err+24(FP)
        CALL    runtime·exitsyscall(SB)
        RET
```

Now, I don't read assembly too well, but I'm pretty sure it is returning EDX in r2. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think they have multiple return values for consistency. As you can see from that table, some architectures return multiple values and if you check a few of the other assembly files from that directory you'll see they move register values to r2.

---

But why DX? This part is still puzzling. Scattered across the web are docs  mentioning on i386 a function is allowed to use both EAX and EDX for return values. For example [System V Application Binary Interface Intel386 Architecture Processor Supplement](https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-i386.pdf):

> **%edx** scratch register; also used to return the upper 32bits of some
>   64bit return types

Later it goes on to say:

> The most significant 32 bits are returned in %edx. The least unsigned
>   long long significant 32 bits are returned in %eax.

Let's try this:

```
uint64_t some_function() {
  return 18446744073709551614LLU;
}
```

Clang ends up producing:

```
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
movl    $-2, %eax
movl    $-1, %edx
popl    %ebp
ret
```

Interestingly, [asm_linux_amd64.s](https://golang.org/src/syscall/asm_linux_amd64.s) seems to do the same thing, giving us a pretext to look at the [System V ABI for AMD64](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf). This also doc mentions in passing, about RDX:

> used to pass 3rd argument to functions; **2nd return register**

But Appendix A deals with Linux Conventions specifically.

> The interface between the C library and the Linux kernel is the same
>   as for the user-level applications with the following differences:
>
> Returning from the syscall, **register %rax contains the result of the
>   system-call.** A value in the range between -4095 and -1 indicates an error,
>   it is -errno.

No mention of RDX for the system call.

---

I won't put my hand in the fire for this (or in general) but I suspect taking DX is not necessary for Linux which doesn't make use of such large return values that they spill out of AX.